# How to use POST method on forms in base template in web.py?

Tags: python, forms, post, web.py

As the title says, I would like to make a search bar form throughout my site. But I don't want to repeat the POST function on all the classes and was hoping there would be an easier way. The search bar is on my base template.

This is my form in my base template:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST" role="search">
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
             <input class="form-control" id="navbarInput-01" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn"><span class="fui-search"></span></button>
            </span>
         </div>
     </div>               
</form>
```

My main python file:

```
import web
from bin import Categories, Search
from web import form

render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout')

db = web.database(dbn="sqlite", db="webDB")

urls = (
    '/', 'home',
    '/about', 'about',
    '/contact', 'contact',
    '/blog', 'blog',
    '/faqs', 'faqs',
    '/tos', 'tos',
    '/cat', Categories.app_cat,
    '/search', Search.app_search
)

class home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.home()

    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
        search = data.search
        raise web.seeother('/search/'+search)
```

I only made a POST method for my home page but I'd like all my pages to have it. I have many classes and copy/pasting this will be tedious.

Comment: Can you show us some code, please? Let's see how you're `POST`ing right now.

Comment: Edited my original post